# reduce the size of the selenium frame

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, web-testing

I do I reduce the size of the selenium frame, in order to increase the frame of the website I am testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the Selenium server in a multiwindow mode:

> -multiWindow: puts you into a mode where the test web site executes in a
>   separate window,  and selenium
>   supports frames

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#server-options

Comment: That link now seems to be broken. :-/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resize the window once you've done multiWindow mode, you can also do getEval("window.resizeTo(X, Y); window.moveTo(0,0);") where X and Y are the width and height of the window you want.